# Cheerio web scraping is not returning the scraped links

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to get the links of a google search and using node js and cheerio to scrape these links. The DOM selector with jQuery works fine in the browser console but when I run my code it outputs an empty array. I am using following code

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios").default;
(async () => {
  const getData = async (url) => {
    const { data } = await axios(url);
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    
     const links = Array.from($('div[class="yuRUbf"] >a')).map((a) => a.href);
    console.log(links);
  };
  getData(
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=Let+You+Love+Me+by+Rita+Ora&sxsrf=ALeKk02Hp5Segi8ShvyrREw3NLZ6p7_BKw:1622526254457&ei=Lsm1YPSzG9WX1fAPvdqTgAg&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj0gqSo3fXwAhXVSxUIHT3tBIAQ8tMDegQIARA7&biw=1517&bih=694"
  );
})();
```

Comment: A couple things: `a.yuRUbf` is not a reliable selector. That's bound to change. Also I absolutely expect that request to fail, since it doesn't fake headers (pretend to be a real browser request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged your code and found out following things which were creating issues

1. You were not passing the user-agent header which was not fetching the desired data so we had to mock user-agent to "browser" so that selector classes were available.
2. While taking href of the anchor tag syntax seems wrong

Adding the revisited code which i tested is working fine.

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");
(async () => {
    const getData = async (url) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36",
            },
        });
        const $ = cheerio.load(data);
        const links = Array.from($('div[class="yuRUbf"] >a')).map((a) => {
            return $(a).attr('href')
        });
        console.log(links);
    };
    getData(
        "https://www.google.com/search?q=Let+You+Love+Me+by+Rita+Ora&sxsrf=ALeKk02Hp5Segi8ShvyrREw3NLZ6p7_BKw:1622526254457&ei=Lsm1YPSzG9WX1fAPvdqTgAg&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj0gqSo3fXwAhXVSxUIHT3tBIAQ8tMDegQIARA7&biw=1517&bih=694"
    );
})();
```

Comment: Your solution works but perfectly, but when I use the **a.href** in the console it works fine but in cheerio its not why is that.

Comment: Because jQuery wraps actual `HTMLElement`s from the browser, and your `a` variable would be one (so you aren't using jQuery in `a.href`, that part is vanilla browser JavaScript) while with cheerio there is no browser.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to get results from Google Search exactly like in a browser, you can use the browser controls library [`Puppeteer`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer). Code and [full code example in online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Scrape-Google-Organic-Results-links-with-NodeJS-SerpApi#index.js)

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const searchString = encodeURI("Let You Love Me by Rita Ora");            // what we want to search
const pagesLimit = 3;                                // limit of pages for getting info
let currentPage = 0;                                  // current page of the search

async function getOrganicResults() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
  for (let i = 0; i < pagesLimit; i++) {
    await page.goto(
      `https://www.google.com/search?q=${searchString}&start=${currentPage * 10}`
    );
    await page.waitForSelector(".yuRUbf > a");

    const links = await page.evaluate(function getUrls() {
      return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".yuRUbf > a")).map((el) =>
        el.getAttribute("href")
      );
    });

    console.log(`----- Page number: ${currentPage + 1} -----`);
    console.log(links);
    currentPage += 1;
  }
    await browser.close();
}

getOrganicResults();
```

Output:

```json
----- Page number: 1 -----
[
   "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_You_Love_Me",
   "https://lickd.co/music/artists/rita-ora/track/let-you-love-me",
   "https://genius.com/Rita-ora-let-you-love-me-lyrics",
   "https://www.pinterest.com/pin/399835273169886541/",
   "https://storyofsong.com/story/let-you-love-me/",
   "https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/35649723/Rita+Ora/Let+You+Love+Me",
   "https://www.amazon.com/Let-You-Love-Me/dp/B07HCGHYQK"
]
----- Page number: 2 -----
[
   "https://nowordsnosong.medium.com/let-you-love-me-rita-ora-93d809477810",
   "https://www.discogs.com/release/12773407-Rita-Ora-Let-You-Love-Me",
   "https://muumuse.com/2018/09/rita-ora-let-you-love-me.html/",
   "https://www.whosampled.com/sample/619657/Rita-Ora-Let-You-Love-Me-The-Mohawks-The-Champ/",
   "https://www.realfeelrecording.com/let-you-love-me-in-studio-rita-ora-cover-by-kayla-melissa-lopez/",
   "https://open.spotify.com/track/6xtcFXSo8H9BZN637BMVKS",
   "https://soundcloud.com/ultraviolet-djs/let-you-love-me-rita-ora-remix",
   "https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ritaora/letyouloveme.html",
   "https://music.apple.com/bs/music-video/let-you-love-me/1437139014",
   "https://therealamericantop40.fandom.com/wiki/Rita_Ora:Let_You_Love_Me"
]
----- Page number: 3 -----
[
   "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9033998/fullcredits",
   "https://www.songfacts.com/facts/rita-ora/let-you-love-me",
   "https://castbox.fm/episode/Download-Music-Mp3%3A-Rita-Ora-%E2%80%93-Let-You-Love-Me-id1674508-id128316226",
   "https://greatsong.net/paroles-let-you-love-me-rita-ora",
   "https://www.tiktok.com/discover/Let-You-Love-Me---Rita-Ora-Song",
   "https://songbpm.com/@rita-ora/let-you-love-me",
   "https://spotalike.com/songs-similar-to/rita-ora-let-you-love-me/3591259",
   "https://secondhandsongs.com/performance/805308",
   "https://www.songexplained.com/rita-ora-let-you-love-me-lyrics-meaning-explained/",
   "https://www.idolator.com/7700799/rita-ora-let-you-love-me-acoustic-video"
]
```

As an alternative solution, you can try to use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi.

The difference is that there's no need to figure out how to make a parser, maintain it, figure out how bypass blocks from Google, and understand how to scale it.

Code to integrate:

```js
const SerpApi = require("google-search-results-nodejs");
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch(process.env.API_KEY);     //your api key from serpapi.com

const searchString = "Let You Love Me by Rita Ora";                                       // what we want to search
const pagesLimit = 2;                                                    // limit of pages for getting info
let currentPage = 0;                                                      // current page of the search

const params = {
  engine: "google",                                                         // search engine
  q: searchString,                                                     // search query
  google_domain: "google.com",                                                // google domain of the search
  gl: "us",                                                            // parameter defines the country to use for the Google search
  hl: "en",                                                            // Parameter defines the language to use for the Google search
};

function getOrganicResults({ organic_results, serpapi_pagination }) {
  console.log(`\nCurrent page: ${serpapi_pagination.current}\n`);

  organic_results.map((result) => {
    console.log(result.link);
  });
}

const getJson = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    search.json(params, resolve);
  });
};

getResults = async () => {
  while (true) {
    if (currentPage > pagesLimit * 10) break;
    const newParams = { ...params, start: currentPage}
    const json = await getJson(newParams);
    await getOrganicResults(json);
    currentPage += 10;
  }
};

getResults();
```

Output:

```json
Current page: 1

"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_You_Love_Me"
"https://lickd.co/music/artists/rita-ora/track/let-you-love-me"
"https://genius.com/Rita-ora-let-you-love-me-lyrics"
"https://www.pinterest.com/pin/399835273169886541/"
"https://storyofsong.com/story/let-you-love-me/"
"https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/35649723/Rita+Ora/Let+You+Love+Me"
"https://nowordsnosong.medium.com/let-you-love-me-rita-ora-93d809477810"

Current page: 2

"https://www.lyrics.com/lyric/35649723/Rita+Ora/Let+You+Love+Me"
"https://nowordsnosong.medium.com/let-you-love-me-rita-ora-93d809477810"
"https://www.whosampled.com/sample/619657/Rita-Ora-Let-You-Love-Me-The-Mohawks-The-Champ/"
"https://open.spotify.com/track/6xtcFXSo8H9BZN637BMVKS"
"https://muumuse.com/2018/09/rita-ora-let-you-love-me.html/"
"https://soundcloud.com/ritaora/let-you-love-me"
"https://www.realfeelrecording.com/let-you-love-me-in-studio-rita-ora-cover-by-kayla-melissa-lopez/"
"https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ritaora/letyouloveme.html"
"https://music.apple.com/bs/music-video/let-you-love-me/1437139014"
"https://therealamericantop40.fandom.com/wiki/Rita_Ora:Let_You_Love_Me"

Current page: 3

"https://therealamericantop40.fandom.com/wiki/Rita_Ora:Let_You_Love_Me"
"https://www.songfacts.com/facts/rita-ora/let-you-love-me"
"https://castbox.fm/episode/Download-Music-Mp3%3A-Rita-Ora-%E2%80%93-Let-You-Love-Me-id1674508-id128316226"
"https://greatsong.net/paroles-let-you-love-me-rita-ora"
"https://www.tiktok.com/discover/Let-You-Love-Me---Rita-Ora-Song"
"https://songbpm.com/@rita-ora/let-you-love-me"
"https://spotalike.com/songs-similar-to/rita-ora-let-you-love-me/3591259"
"https://secondhandsongs.com/performance/805308"
"https://www.songexplained.com/rita-ora-let-you-love-me-lyrics-meaning-explained/"
"https://lyricstranslate.com/en/rita-ora-let-you-love-me-lyrics.html"
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.